# Permutation of keys that guarantees different hashes

Tags: hash

Suppose I have two values to be hashed, $x$ and $y$. Is there a hash function $H$ with the following properties?

$H(x) = H(y), \; H(m(x)) \neq H(m(y))$

Where $m$ is a permutation function that may depend on $H$.

**Edit**: The corrected question is, if $H(x) = H(y)$, them is it possible to make any permutation $m$ so that $H(m(x)) \neq H(m(y))$?

Comment: So if $x==y$, then $H(x)\neq H(y)$?

Comment: You might want to clarify your question. The only functions that satisfy $H(x) = H(y)\ \forall x \ne y$ are constant ones, and those obviously cannot satisfy the second criterion. So, as written, the answer is trivially "no."

Comment: @IlmariKaronen not necessarily. Hash functions may collide, so for different values $x$ and $y$, a hash $H$ may yield the same value.

The point, if this happens, and only if this happens, can I make any kind of change $m$ to $x$ and $y$ that will guarantee a different result of $H$?

Comment: @petermlm: Yes, but if $H(x) = H(y)$ for *all* $x$ and $y$ (that's what $\forall$ means), then the output of $H$ is constant.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, you are right. I am indeed mistaken. It's not for all $x$ and $y$ that I wan't the property. I'll edit the question.

It is just, if $x$ and $y$ have the same hash, them is it possible to make a small permutation $m$ such that $H(m(x)) \neq H(m(y))$?

Comment: @petermlm: please confirm (or infirm) that the question is as follows: given two fixed _distinct_ $x$ and $y$, is there a (hash) function $H$ with $H(x)=H(y)$ and such that for any permutation $m$ _distinct from identity_, $H(m(x))\neq H(m(y))$ ?

Comment: @fgrieu, yes that is it

Comment: @fgrieu: I suspect the OP actually wants $$\exists H,m\ \forall x,y: (x \ne y \land H(x) = H(y)) \implies H(m(x)) \ne H(m(y)),$$ rather than $$\exists H,x,y\ \forall m: x \ne y \land H(x) = H(y) \land (m \ne {\rm id} \implies H(m(x)) \ne H(m(y))).$$

Answer (score 6):

I [assume](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31753/permutation-of-keys-that-guarantees-different-hashes#comment73810_31753) you're asking whether there exists a hash function $H: \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^\ell$, and a permutation $m: \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^*$, such that $$H(x) = H(y) \implies H(m(x)) \ne H(m(y))$$ for all $x \ne y$.

The answer, alas, is no — there is no such $H$ and $m$.

If there was, we could construct a collision-free hash function $H': \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^{2\ell}$ as $$H'(x) = H(x) \| H(m(x)).$$  But since the set $\{0,1\}^*$ is infinite, while $\{0,1\}^{2\ell}$ is finite, this is clearly impossible.

More generally, the same argument shows that no such $H$ and $m$ can exist if the input domain of $H$ has more than $n^2$ elements, where $n = 2^\ell$ is the number of possible outputs of $H$.